How to assign a value to field based on input field in Jolt
request:
{
  "name": "Aranav"
}

Expected Response
{
  "name": "Aranav",
  "idCode":"0001"
}

there are 100 students for each student there is specified idCode. Based on the name in request we have to add idCode for that student. How to achieve this in Jolt. we have list of names and list of idcodes for each student.

Hi MAdhavi, seems those idCode values are missing, can you please add them into the request JSON as well ?
